# Unable to shrink volume by needed amount despite available space in Windows Disk Manager

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd, disk-management

I am trying to create a new partition on my SSD and need to shrink my C: partition to do so. According to the "this PC" page, I have 36.1GB available on my C: drive. However, when I attempt to shrink my C: drive in Disk Manager I am told that there is only 9521MB available to shrink and am unable to shrink any further. I need at least 25GB for this new partition.

Comment: Windows requires 25GB free on `C:` for version updates [21H2, 22H1, etc.] and IIRC there is a way to bypass that covered on Superuser, however I personally don't recommend it. Even if your user data folders within `%UserProfile%` are stored on a partition other than `C:` shrinking `C:` to 25GB wouldn't be advised unless this is a VM - accounting for the `pagefile.sys`, `hiberfil.sys`, and temp files, it's taking a chance of running out of storage on `C:` for normal system operations. _(General FYI: it's generally recommended to ensure 10% of a partition is available)_

Comment: @JW0914 I have shrunk the volume by the allowed 9.5GB and after clearing some space I still have over 25GB, yet cannot shrink any further.

Comment: *yet cannot shrink any further* and you really shouldn't, reasons above. If this is to install a dual-boot then please (1) read carefully my answer to your other question, understand it, especially the risks and caveats, and (2) consider a virtual machine instead because **you don't have the minimal requirements - not enough space - to install a dual-boot with Ubuntu.** You'll end up with 2 OSes in serious risk of running out of space and became unbootable.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have 50GB available. ~10GB I have left unallocated, leaving 40GB unused and stuck in my C partition, if I can make this unallocated and use it on my Ubuntu install this should be enough. 25GB is the minimal system requirement for Ubuntu.

Comment: Again, *it's generally recommended to ensure 10% of a partition is available* as **free space**. And 25GB is indeed the minimum for a basic installation and a few programs. Depending on the usage scenario you may need more, a lot more, and the same rule above applies to Ubuntu as well.